# How know the modal dialog closed?

Tags: oracle-apex

I am using APEX 21.1. I have a page with interactive report. It's default link opens a modal dialog page. And I added two columns of type Link to it's query. For example,

```
select deptno, dname, loc, 'Open Examination Dialog' as examination_dialog, 'Open followup dialog' as followup_dialog from dept;
```

I need to open a page in a new tab and send it parameters when examination dialog is closed. And do the same but with different parameters when followup dialog is closed. So, I need to know which dialog is closed and based on that execute a javaScript dynamic action with code like

```
apex.navigation.openInNewWindow();
```

I tried setting static id's for examination dialog column and followup dialog and created 2 dynamic actions of type "dialog closed" and set the columns' static id's as the jQuery selector which called the dialog page. But nothing happens.
Can I know which dialog is closed and execute a dynamic action based on that?
Here is a simulation...

```
ws=ESLAM_WS
un= forhelp  
pwd=Forhelppwd$  
app=TEST2_FOR_ME  
pages= 2 and 6
```

The IR in page 2 has a column(Link) called "open dialog". It should open page 6 which is a modal. Page 2 has a "Dialog Closed" dynamic action that should display an alert when the dialog is closed. But the dynamic action does not fire. There should be another column that opens another modal dialog which when closing too, I need to execute another dynamic action, for example, another alert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create 2 dynamic actions, one for each dialog page. Add this javascript expression as client side condition for the dynamic action (In addition to the standard On Dialog Closed) that should fire when page 6 is closed:

```
this.data && this.data.dialogPageId && this.data.dialogPageId == 6
```

Do the same for the 2nd dynamic action but the appropriate value for `this.data.dialogPageId`

In the dynamic action javascript, the *this* refers to the triggeringelement. Best way to look into this yourself is to execute javascript in a dynamic action true action (just for developing)

```
console.log(this);
```

You'll notice that there is an attribute dialogPageId in the data with the value of the closed window. So this condition will yield true if the dynamic action was fired on close of that specific page.

[image: Dynamic Action condition]

Comment: It checks that the dialog page is page 6. I'm using it in one of my apps. Did you try it ?

Comment: I can not know if it works. The "When" section of the DA has attributes "EVENT= Dialog Closed", "selection type=javaScript expression" and the expression is "window". If I put your code as a client side condition, it will fire either way because the triggering element is "window". And that's what happened when I tested. I think there is a way to refer to the column as the triggering element but I do not know how.

Comment: Works fine for me using setup in the screenshot (note that mine is on page26). If I close dialog page 26 the actions fire. If I change that code to another page number and close dialog page 26 the actions do not fire. Changed the wording a bit because it is indeed confusing.

Comment: 1- Did you put the expression as a client-side condition for "dialog closed" dynamic action?
2- Is page 26 the master dialog linked to the report page? Or is it a dialog that's called using a column(Link) like in my case?

Comment: This is a form and report. Page 25 is the report, page 26 is the form - called by the edit button which should be the same

Comment: You don't need expression "window" - just the region like in my screenshot. Check the app "TEST2_FOR_ME - Koen" in your workspace I'm showing it there.

Comment: - With "window" or "region" set as expression, it works because both have "data" object which has "dialogPageId". 
- I think no need for "this.data && this.data.dialogPageId". I tested with only "this.data.dialogPageId == pageNo i.e 3" and it worked. 
- I am inclined to understand how things work...
Does "this.data" and this.data.dialogPageId return boolean? Otherwise how are they appended to the condition?!
- last point: I am pretty sure there is a more direct and appropriate way to catch the calling object i.e column, do not you think? I tried setting static id for the column and set ...

Comment: ....set selection type to jQuery selector and set #THE_STATIC_ID as the jQuery selector but it did not work!

Comment: I'm using my solution in my own apps - it works. I believe this solves your question. Can you please mark it as solved ?